Generic intersections of the preimage and a submanifold
Let $f: X \to Y$ be a smooth map between manifolds of the same dimension. Let $Z$ be a submanifold of $X$ of codimension 1. By Sard's theorem, for almost every $y \in Y$, $f^{-1}(y)$ is a 0-dimensional manifold. Is it true that for almost all $y \in Y$, $f^{-1}(y) \cap Z = \emptyset$? I considered the set $\text{Reg}(f) \setminus f(Z)$, but was not sure how to argue $f(Z)$ is a null set. I've also seen an argument (in a particular setting) that claims that for almost all $y \in Y$, $f^{-1}(y) \cap Z$ is a submanifold of $f^{-1}(y)$ of codimension 1. This finishes the proof, but I don't know whether/why the claim holds in general.

Lemma: A $C^1$ map maps sets of volume $0$ to sets of volume $0$.
